# What's wrong with my nginx configuration with docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a docker environment with 3 containers: **frontend** (angular), **backend** (dotnet) and **nginx**.

I'm trying to configure nginx with a **proxy_pass** to direct the **/api** location to my API from one of the containers.

**This is my nginx configuration:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sitr-app:80;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://sitr-api:80;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**These are my Dockerfiles:**

**API dotnet:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SITR.Web.Host.dll", "--environment=Staging"]
```

**Frontend angular:**

```
FROM nginx
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
```

**nginx**

```
FROM nginx
COPY default_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**My docker-compose file**

```
version: '3.0'

services:

    sitr-api:
        image: sitr-api
        container_name: sitr-api
        environment:
            ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging
        ports:
            - "9901:80"
        volumes:
            - "./Host-Logs:/app/App_Data/Logs"

    sitr-app:
        image: sitr-app
        container_name: sitr-app
        ports:
            - "9902:80"
    
    nginx: 
        image: sitr-nginx
        container_name: sitr-nginx
        depends_on: 
          - sitr-app
          - sitr-api
        ports: 
          - "81:80"
```

The **containers are working** because I was able to access localhost:9901 (backend) and localhost:9902 (frontend).

My frontend accessing through nginx on localhost:81 is also working, but the proxy_pass to my **localhost:81/api** backend is not working (**http 404**).

What is wrong with my nginx configuration?

Comment: Does your backend listen to the `/api` route? Your nginx conf doesn't have a rewrite, so `localhost:81/api` will passed on to the backend as `http://sitr-ap:80/api`. Normally you would want to add something like `rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;` before the `proxy_pass` to get rid of the leading `/api` before passing it on.

Comment: @super it worked, that was exactly what it was. If you can put as an answer I will accept it here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting response based on @super's comment.
According to his comment, it was only necessary to do a **rewrite** to remove **/api** when he redirects.

The specific line I needed to add with the regex to remove **/api** is this:

```
rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;
```

**This is the complete nginx configuration:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sitr-app:80;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    
    location /api {
        rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://sitr-api:80;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```